# How is String Pointer allocated on stack?

Tags: rust, stack

```
fn main() {
    let start = 1;              // 0x16fdda220
    let a = 1;                  // 0x16fdda224
    let s = String::from("x");  // 0x16fdda228
    let ss = &s;                // 0x16fdda228
    let b = 1;                  // 0x16fdda24c
    println!("{:p} {:p} {:p} {:p} {:p}", &start, &a, &s, &b, ss);
}
```

I have comment the printed addresses on the right. My question is:

1. Why the difference of start and a is 4 bytes? I expect it to be 8 bytes, because I'm on a 64bit Macbook
2. Why the difference of b and s is 36 bytes? I expect it to be 32 bytes: 8 bytes for String's internal buffer pointer, 8 bytes for String's length, 8 bytes for String's capacity and 8 bytes for ss

Answer (score 4):

> Why the difference of start and a is 4 bytes? I expect it to be 8 bytes, because I'm on a 64bit Macbook

Since a type was not specified integers are assumed to be `i32`s. If you want a 64bit type, you need to specify it explicitly. This is so they they coerce to the same type on every system. If you want an integer that changes depending on the word  size you can use a `usize` or `isize`.

> Why the difference of b and s is 36 bytes? I expect it to be 32 bytes: 8 bytes for String's internal buffer pointer, 8 bytes for String's length, 8 bytes for String's capacity and 8 bytes for ss

Internally a `String` is just a `Vec<u8>`. In the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html) it describes how a `Vec<u8>` contains a pointer, length, and capacity giving it a total length of 24 bytes in your case. An `&String` does indeed take up another 8 bytes for the pointer leaving the last 4 unknown bytes directly before `b`.

While I am not entirely sure, I am guessing that this is a side product of how you called `String::from`. The compiler may have determined that `String::from` required some space on the stack to return the result and shifted `d` over to make room assuming that it would be initialized before the call.

**Either way though, it doesn't really tell us much since this was with optimization disabled.** It leaves spaces since it never attempted to remove them in the first place. If you run this code snippet in release mode (Enabled via `--release`) it completely removes these spaces.


**Edit:** Rust also currently has an issue with not re-using stack space of moved objects. While somewhat unlikely for this use case, you can see the tracking issue here: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/85230

Answer (score 1):

> Why the difference of start and a is 4 bytes? I expect it to be 8 bytes, because I'm on a 64bit Macbook

Because the default integer type is `i32`, and it occupies 4 bytes. You can specify `start` as `1usize` and then it may be eight bytes, but note that nothing is guaranteed about stack layout.

> Why the difference of b and s is 36 bytes? I expect it to be 32 bytes: 8 bytes for String's internal buffer pointer, 8 bytes for String's length, 8 bytes for String's capacity and 8 bytes for ss

> nothing is guaranteed about stack layout.

Answer (score 1):

> Why the difference of start and a is 4 bytes? I expect it to be 8 bytes, because I'm on a 64bit Macbook

The default type for integers in Rust, when unconstrained by other requirements, is `i32` (4 bytes). `start` and `a` are therefore both 4-byte signed integers.

> Why the difference of b and s is 36 bytes? I expect it to be 32 bytes: 8 bytes for String's internal buffer pointer, 8 bytes for String's length, 8 bytes for String's capacity and 8 bytes for ss

In debug mode, on my system the difference is 24 bytes, not 36.  Likely, `ss` is being optimized away.

In release mode, the difference is 4 bytes, hinting that the compiler was able to eliminate the entire heap allocation for the string (since it's never used) and therefore eliminate most of `String`'s data members as well.

---

Basically, there's no point in trying to reason about the layout of the stack. The compiler and optimizer have complete freedom to arrange things however they want as long as the observable behavior of the program isn't changed.